# How to find number of blocks in cache?

Tags: cpu-cache

Suppose a computer using direct mapped cache has 512KB of main memory and a cache of 4 Bytes, where each cache size is 64KB.
1)Find Number of blocks in cache.

Comment: i dont understand what is a cache of 4 Bytes, where each cache size is 64KB. Did  cache size mean block size

Comment: Your question probably misses at least one word  : "and a cache _____ of 4 bytes". Maybe a cache line ? (which would still be very small)